# Standard field Type on Task not available for Reporting

Tags: reporting, tasks, activities

I want to build a 'Tasks and Events' Report. So I created a New report

Standard field '**Type**'  which is a Picklist is not available to be selected when creating a report.

****What I tried so far****

Setup > Report Type > Add the field in PageLayout of the Report
However, the field **Type** is not in the grid 'Fields Available for Reports'

Could someone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score -1):

If you can see the field in the custom report type layout but the user can't see it when creating/editing a report, you might want to check the Field-Level Security for that user and field

If the users are external, you'll need to check the public FLS settings:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_reporting_tasks_events.htm&type=5

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. My question is not about who sees what and permission to the field. My question is asking if there is a workaround to make a  standard field  'Type' on Task available for reporting.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood you :) you can't add the Type field to custom report types, can only access the Type field on the standard report types per activity-enabled object (e.g. Tasks with Opportunities) and the Activity Type field on the standard Tasks and Events report type. As a workaround, you can create a custom text or picklist field and set up workflow to copy the standard Type field value into the new custom field

Comment: Thanks @Instread. Thats what i ended up doing